Al modificar la ruta de un proyecto no redirige correctamente (.htaccess)
Es mi primera pregunta así que espero hacerla bien.
Tengo un proyecto en local (MAMP). En el panel de configuración de MAMP utilizo como "Document Root" la carpeta "public" del proyecto. La ruta sería algo así:
"C:\MAMP\htdocs\proyecto\public"
Dentro de public tengo este .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . / [L]
</IfModule>

Pongo http://localhost y funciona.
Esta sería una captura de la estructura del proyecto:

El problema viene cuando intento que la ruta raíz o Document Root en MAMP sea directamente "htdocs".

Si introduzco http://localhost/proyecto se puede ver el directorio del proyecto.
Para redireccionarlo a "public" he creado otro .htaccess en la raiz del proyecto (además del que tengo en public) con el siguiente código:
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

He probado distintas combinaciones que se me han ocurrido/he encontrado, pero no consigo que funcione.
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] debería devolver, por ejemplo, '/inicio' o '/gestor' (es lo que me devuelve en el primer caso), pero en su lugar me devuelve la ruta '/proyecto/'
Muchas gracias.

No se nada de MAMP, pero algo de apache, y diria que lo que tienes que hacer es crearte un Virtualhost que apunte a C:\MAMP\htdocs\proyecto\public, pues me parece que lo que estas contando tan solo sirve para un único sitio web, el que se asigna por defecto en apache, y usando directivas VirtualHost puedes crear más dominios (aunque solo se resuelvan internamente en tu Mac toqueteando el /etc/hosts). Es decir, en el /etc/hosts creas una entrada tipo 127.0.0.1 proyecto.com www.proyecto.com y luego, en apache, creas su virtualhost apuntando a esa carpeta.

es correcto, en realidad todo esto se maneja con virtul host, ademas que ese metodo te permite manejas multiples protectos y multiples versiones php

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Es posible lograr la configuración de Laragon implementando Virtual Host y la ejecución de múltiples versiones de php al mismo tiempo?

hay encontrarars una respuesta orientada a Laragon pero es aplicable a WAMP y XAMP y MAMP y todos los AMP ... donde este la A de apache ...
